# How do I use a running che 7

Tags: kubernetes, eclipse-che

I'm having issues using a che application I have running in minikube.  Does anyone know an easy way out of this?

I think I have it running:

```
al@cougar:~$ kubectl -n che get pod
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
che-9644775cc-mgrn6                 1/1     Running   0          38m
devfile-registry-696845fc9f-ps62l   1/1     Running   0          38m
plugin-registry-7b94d46db7-4fhhd    1/1     Running   0          38m
```

I thought chectl would expose it, but that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
al@cougar:~$ minikube service list
|--------------|----------------------|--------------|-----|
|  NAMESPACE   |         NAME         | TARGET PORT  | URL |
|--------------|----------------------|--------------|-----|
| cert-manager | cert-manager         | No node port |
| cert-manager | cert-manager-webhook | No node port |
| che          | che-host             | No node port |
| che          | devfile-registry     | No node port |
| che          | plugin-registry      | No node port |
| default      | kubernetes           | No node port |
| kube-system  | kube-dns             | No node port |
|--------------|----------------------|--------------|-----|
```

I think I can see the ports exposed by che-host, do I have to set a load balancer up?:

```
al@cougar:~$ kubectl get services --namespace=che
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
che-host           ClusterIP   10.105.232.58   <none>        8080/TCP,8087/TCP   55m
devfile-registry   ClusterIP   10.101.12.68    <none>        8080/TCP            55m
plugin-registry    ClusterIP   10.99.88.115    <none>        8080/TCP            55m
```

It looks like it's running on 8080 on the container:

```
al@cougar:~$ kubectl get svc che-host --namespace=che
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
che-host   ClusterIP   10.105.232.58   <none>        8080/TCP,8087/TCP   79m
```

I've also seen "Kubectl edit" and 8080 was called http and 8087 was called metrics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command as below to expose a deployment named `hello-node` via a service to be accessible from outside the kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080
```

On Minikube, the LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the minikube service command

```
minikube service hello-node
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  I was able to figure it out from there.